# Sum of consecutive same rows in R

Tags: r

I have data like below given for ex.

```
V1    V2    V3
6.9  6.2   4590
6.9  6.2   1340
7.1  6.2   3000
7.2  6.3   3490
```

the output i am trying to get is

```
V1   V2  V3
6.9  6.2 avg(4590,1340)
7.1  6.2 3000
7.2  6.3 3490
```

the purpose is to find avg of V3 if consecutive values in V1 & V2 are same.

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 3):

We can use `aggregate`

```
aggregate(V3~., df1, mean)
#  V1  V2   V3
#1 6.9 6.2 2965
#2 7.1 6.2 3000
#3 7.2 6.3 3490
```

---

Or

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, list(V3= mean(V3)) ,.(V1, V2)]
```

---

Or

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(V1, V2) %>%
   summarise(V3= mean(V3))
```

---

Or with `sqldf`

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf('select V1, V2,  
        avg(V3) as V3 
        from df1
        group by V1, V2')
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(V1 = c(6.9, 6.9, 7.1, 7.2), 
 V2 = c(6.2, 6.2, 6.2, 
 6.3), V3 = c(4590L, 1340L, 3000L, 3490L)),
.Names = c("V1", "V2", 
"V3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: Hey Thanks alot akrun, i tried 2nd option, but i also need a row number from the source data set corresponding to avg. like in example its 2 for 1st avg. and so on..

Comment: @NitinPatil YOu can use `add_rownames` from `dplyr`

Comment: Hey just a little more help.. its now somehow sorting the data which i don't want, i mean order is imp for me.

Comment: @NitinPatil What kind of order are you talking about?  If you look at the `aggregate` output, isn't it giving the same as your expected?

Comment: @NitinPatil Perhaps `df1 %>% group_by(V1,V2) %>% mutate(V3=mean(V3)) %>% unique()`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `plyr` solution:

```
require(plyr)

> ddply(df, .(V1, V2), summarise, V2=mean(V2), V3=mean(V3))
   V1  V2   V3
1 6.9 6.2 2965
2 7.1 6.2 3000
3 7.2 6.3 3490
```

Note that, in SQL terms, you want to group by the combination of columns `V1` and `V2`, which is represented in the second parameter as `.(V1, V2)`.

**Data:**

```
df <- data.frame(V1=c(6.9, 6.9, 7.1, 7.2),
                 V2=c(6.2, 6.2, 6.2, 6.3),
                 V3=c(4590, 1340, 3000, 3490))
```